# Are MAC addresses of hosts always visible to other hosts on a WLAN?

Tags: network, wifi, anonymity

Is there a way of completely hiding one's MAC address so it does not appear in the ARP caches of other hosts? Or is periodically changing it the only solution to achieve anonymity with regards to a MAC address?

Comment: How would periodically changing MAC achieve anonymity on a LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MAC addresses are always visible to other hosts on the same LAN, regardless of whether or not it is wireless. In fact, they are fundamentally necessary, as they are how two local devices communicate with each other. There is no way to disable the usage of MAC addresses, however you can *spoof* them, essentially assigning a new, arbitrary address to a device. As long as it does not collide with any other existing addresses, it will be used to route traffic to it as usual.

Note, however, that an attacker-controlled wireless access point may not be fooled by a spoofed MAC address, since all devices have their own unique quirks when it comes to establishing a wireless connection. This [Wi-Fi fingerprinting](https://papers.mathyvanhoef.com/asiaccs2016.pdf) can correlate the identity of two devices even if the MAC address has been changed. Anonymity may be hard to achieve when you are connecting to a router that is not under your control. Assume that that router knows which machine is yours. If you just want to avoid appearing in hosts' ARP caches, then changing your MAC address is sufficient.